# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED while installing cairocffi with pip

Tags: pip, ssl-certificate, weasyprint

When I run:

```
pip install cairocffi==0.9.0
```

I get:

```
...
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852) -- Some packages may not be found!
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs due to some SSL certificates missing. To solve this I ran:

```
pip install certifi==2017.4.17
```